# pytest django TestCase give strange failures with `--pdb`

Tags: django, pytest, pdb, pytest-django

I have a very simple class which fails on any version of pytest>3.0.0. When I invoke the tests with `--pdb`.

```
from django.test import TestCase


class TestTestCase(TestCase):
    """Tests for the TestCase class."""

    def test_that_client_exists(self):
        """Assert that the class has a client."""
        assert self.client
```

I am using the following version:

- platform Linux
- Python 2.7.11
- pytest-3.3.1
- py-1.5.2
- pluggy-0.6.0
- django-2.9.2

And I get the following error:

```
self = <myproject.tests.test_test_case.TestTestCase testMethod=test_that_client_exists>

    def test_that_client_exists(self):
        """Assert that the class has a client."""
>       assert self.client
E       AttributeError: 'TestTestCase' object has no attribute 'client'
```

However, if I downgrade to `pytest==3.0.0` and `pluggy-0.3.1`, the code executes without any issues. My question is this, what is going on? What could be causing this?

It is as if pytest is calling the `test_that_client_exists` but is not calling `__call__` which calls `_pre_setup`.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: The test runs with a clean django project (Python 2.7.10, `django==1.11.9`, `pytest==3.3.2`, `pytest-django==3.1.2`). There must be something else there.

Comment: So this issue disappears if I remove `--pdb` from the invocation of the tests.

Comment: [possibly related issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1977)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, pytest doesn't setup the class the way a standard django test is expected to be called.

I would remove the TestCase inheritance and manually add in the client.

```
from django.test import Client


class TestTestCase():
    """Tests for the TestCase class."""

    client = Client()

    def test_that_client_exists(self):
        """Assert that the class has a client."""
        assert self.client
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately, this is a shared code base with many such classes, I am hoping someone can shed light on the underlying cause. For simplicity I broke it down the simplest class I could create to exemplify the issue.

Comment: Im not sure I can offer much more help then. My only recomendation would be to see if pytest-django would be helpful:

http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html